# How do I angle Sandbag's up-special?

Tags: super-smash-flash-2

In [SSF2](https://mcleodgaming.com/games/ssf2), Sandbag's up-special has him dropping a bomb on himself to propel him upwards.

CPU players appear to be able to angle the move in a desirable direction, but I am unable to do this consistently. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move operates similarly to Fox's up-special move (input: up+special, direction), with one exception: Sandbag may only angle the move in 3 directions: up, backwards, and backwards-up.

In order to angle toward the stage, then, Sandbag needs to be facing away from it when he performs his up-special.